# Can I change the default Markdown Preview font color in VS Code Jupyter Notebooks?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, markdown

I am using Visual Studio Code, and dealing with a .ipynb file.

For the dark theme of VS Code, the default Markdown Preview font color is gray.

What I want to do is, changing the markdown font color to white and set this color as the default.

(for high contrast, as the background is black)

I can change the font color by `<font color = something>`, but I need to put that tag in every markdown cell.

So I want to change default setting of markdown, not changing the whole VS Code theme.

I have not found that setting yet.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: what is the TextMate Scope of the Markdown text, if it is specific like `....notebook.markdown` you can customize the color in `settings.json` and also for a specific theme

Answer (score 1):

I exhausted the features I know about and none of them really worked (at least- not as well as I'd like them to), so I'm a little tempted to think that it's not possible at the time of this writing (of course- I could easily be wrong, and I'd be very happy to be wrong):

- Technically speaking you can do this with the `foreground` property of the `workbench.colorCustomizations` setting, but that'll affect much more than just the colour of text in markdown cells, so I'm not sure if this will be a good solution for you.

  This is also mentioned in this issue ticket: [Text in Jupyter notebook markup is hard to read because it is gray and incorrectly anti-aliased #138947](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/138947)

  There are other related colour customization points, such as `textLink.foreground`, `textPreformat.foreground`, `textSeparator.foreground`, `textLink.activeForeground`, and `textBlockQuote.background` just to name a few.
- The `markdown.styles` doesn't seem to apply to Markdown cells in Jupyter Notebooks.
- Usually for code-related things, you can use [startup files](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/tutorial.html#startup-files), but that seems like it doesn't work for Markdown cells (go figure).

If you ever decide to create an issue ticket about this to the VS Code Jupyter extension maintainers, please comment here with a link to your issue ticket, or suggest an edit to this post to add a link to it.